# What are some ways of modelling usage of a resource?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, unevenly-spaced-time-series

Currently working on modelling the number of people in a local gym.  The gym has kept immaculate data on how many people are in the gym for the past year or so.

They would like to make predictions of the type "At 8 AM there should be 100 people in the gym.  At 9 AM there should be 120 people in the gym".

Data consists of a timestamp and a head count.  Here are my thoughts:

1) Observations are highly correlated.  If the head count is 100 around 8, it should be around 100 around 9.

2) The data is technically count data, so I think a strict statistician may avoid OLS if inference is desired.  I don't think the gym really cares about inference and just wants a predictive model, so I am inclined to do OLS.

3) Time series may not be completely out of the question, but since the timestamps are not at similar increments, I think that may preclude most TS methods. Further more, the gym is closed between 11:30 pm and 6:00 am, so I'm not sure how to tackle that either.

So here are my questions:

1) How can I account for the autocorrelation in head count?  Assuming OLS does a good job of prediction, what pitfalls should I be weary of?

2) Are there time series methods to account for irregular time observations?  If so, how could I account for closures?

Comment: How would a point prediction not be [inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_inference)? You're still obtaining parameter estimates.

Comment: With irregular time, maybe a model with a latent (unobserved) underlying autocorrelated process which gives the expectation for a poisson (or negative binomial) observed process?